# Slutsky's theorem for infinite space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence

Assume that we have a sequences of random elements $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$, taking values, for example in the space $\ell_{2}$. Assume that
$$
X_{n}\overset{d}{\to} X
$$
and
$$
Y_{n}\overset{p}{\to} c \in \ell_{2},
$$
i.e. $c$ is some constant possibly infinite vector in $\ell_{2}$.

Is the following correct?
$$
X_{n} \cdot Y_{n}\overset{d}{\to} X \cdot c ,
$$
where we multiply component wise.

I know it works for finite dimensional vectors and matrixes, but I can not find a more general statement of this result.

Also, would it be true if, instead, we consider
$$
<X_{n} , Y_{n}>\overset{d}{\to} < X, c >,
$$
where $< , >$ is the inner product in $\ell_{2}$.

I am trying to figure it out by considering product space $\ell_{2}\times \ell_{2}$ and then considering the convergence in the product space and then continuous mapping theorem.

Comment: How do you multiply two elements of $\ell^2$?

Comment: I updated the question. We multiply component-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are true. Just as in the case of Slutsky's theorem for scalar-valued random variables (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB3) for example), one can show that $(X_n,Y_n)\overset{d}{\to} (X,c)$. Moreover, the maps $\ell_2\times \ell_2\to \ell_2,\,(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$ and $\ell_2\times \ell_2\to \mathbb{K},\,(x,y)\mapsto \langle x,y\rangle$ are continuous. Now the result follows from the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) (which is rather trivial in this case).

Comment: hm... for continuous mapping theorem we need the convergence of random elements. Is it a trivial result that $(X_{n}, Y_{n})$ converges in distribution to $(X, c)$ in the product space?

Comment: Not necessarily trivial, but the proof works exactly the same as the one in the first link for scalar-valued random variables.

Comment: I wonder, why I can not find this result in any course on asymptotic theory? From what I understand, infinite spaces behaves very different to each other.

Comment: That I cannot tell you. But you find both ingredients ($X_n\overset{d}{\to} X$, $Y_n\overset{P}{\to}c\implies (X_n,Y_n)\overset{d}{\to}(X,C)$ and $Z_n\overset{d}{\to}{Z}\implies f(Z_n)\overset{d}{\to}f(Z)$) in books studying random variables with values in metric spaces.

Comment: well, could you, please, give a reference to some book. I haven't found any...